# Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 making navbar-toggler always visible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find any setting of navbar-toggleable-* that allows the navbar-toggler to be always visible.

I can keep it visible all the way to large using navbar-toggleable-xl but once the browser reaches xl it disappears because of this class:

```
.navbar-toggleable-xl .navbar-toggler {
  display: none;
}
```

My only option to make this work the way I want seems to be commenting out this class or overriding it. Are there other options?

Comment: Will you please provide your full code of navbar-toggler?
You want to visible in all  media??? Like Desktop, Mobile......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever thought of removing the `navbar-toggleable-*` class altogether?

Comment: Yeah that is pretty much the direction I took.  BS4 gives you other options for rolling your own "responsive" navbar.  If you like the way they use navbar-toggleable it surely makes life easier and by all means use it.  It just doesn't work the way I need it to.  So I moved on to their other classes that allow me to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Actually after much research with Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 and the navbar-toggleable class I get what they are trying to do.  What I'm doing kind of goes against the grain of the design of the navbar-toggleable class.

Fortunately BS4 gives you much flexibility with the navbar and flex utilities that you can really roll your own "responsive" design.